# How to get multiple value for `Product` from Database?

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

In the below code I am trying to find Minimum rate using `MIN(rate)`, Maximum rate using `MAX(rate)`, and Average Value of rate using `AVG(rate)` what I get is the Product for `MIN(rate) | MAX(rate) | AVG(rate)` is same result

```
    $this->db->select('MIN(rate),MAX(rate),AVG(rate)');
    $this->db->select('my_rates.product');
    $this->db->from('my_rates');
    $query = $this->db->get();
    return $query->result_array();
```

how to get `MIN(rate)` Product `MAX(rate)` Product `AVG(rate)` Separate

Comment: Why are you using 2 select functions there?

Comment: `my_rates` is table for product and rate and products are column so and I want to find `MIN` | `MAX` | `AVG` value for `rate` what I get is all rate values separately but I also want the products of the rates Like I have `MIN(rate)` with different product and `MAX(rate)` for different product

Comment: Do you want to select min / max / avg rates from the entire population and if you have products, which rate happens to be the same as the min , max, or avg, then display their names as well? (for avg rate you may not have a product that has the same rate as the average)

Comment: Yes for average it will set the default product but for the min and max value rate I am getting same product

Comment: I think you'll need to use `group_by`. `$this->db->group_by('product_id');`

Comment: I tried by that but the result is same as before

Answer (score 1):

I suggest the following:

```
$query = $this->db->select('product, MIN(rate) as min, MAX(rate) as max, AVG(rate) as avg', FALSE)
    ->get('my_rates');
return $query->result_array();
```

The minimum value will be accessible with the key min, the maximum value with the key max, the average with the key avg and my_rates.product with the key product.

CodeIgniter's query builder is really good documented [here](https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/database/query_builder.html)